# Как разбить слово на несколько частей по 3-5 символов? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

Приложение генерирует рандомный набор символов, как этот набор символов разделить на несколько частей по 3-5 символов и добавить все в массив? Swift

Comment: Набор это что - массив, строка, множество?

Comment: Генерируется строка

Comment: бери подстроки длиной 3-5 символов и добавляй в массив.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял задачу, то так:

```swift
    let word = "Hello"
    var result = ""
    let terminator = "-"
    let interval = 2
    
    for (i, char) in word.enumerated() {
        if i.isMultiple(of: interval) && i != 0 {
            result += terminator + String(char)
        } else {
            result += String(char)
        }
    }
    
    print(result)
```

Напечататет: "He-ll-o"